# Melee Attack against a Turned Creature

Tags: dnd-3.5e, cleric

Situation: Cleric moves adjacent to an undead creature, uses Turn Undead, and successfully turns the creature.
The creature cannot flee because *insert reason here,* so instead cowers and continues to do so on its turn in the initiative.

Should the cleric elect to make a melee attack against said creature, would this action break the turn effect similar to approaching to within 10ft?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## The cleric's approach—for whatever reason—ends the turning effect

[Turn or Rebuke Undead](http://dndsrd.net/specialAttacks.html#turn) on Effect and Duration of Turning says

> Turned undead flee from you by the best and fastest means available to them. They flee for 10 rounds (1 minute). **If they cannot flee, they cower (giving any attack rolls against them a +2 bonus). If you approach within 10 feet of them, however, they overcome being turned and act normally.** (You can stand within 10 feet without breaking the turning effect—you just can’t approach them.) You can attack them with ranged attacks (from at least 10 feet away), and others can attack them in any fashion, without breaking the turning effect. (*Player's Handbook* 159)

(Emphasis mine.) A turned undead creature always flees from the cleric until it can't. But, if the cleric's adjacent to the undead creature, successfully turns the undead creature, and the undead creature simply *can't* flee, the undead creature cowers, and the cleric has *not* approached, so the cleric should be able to make melee attacks against the adjacent cornered undead creature without the turn effect ending.

Thus it's *not* the cleric's melee attacks that end the turning effect. Even under normal conditions, if a cleric can make melee attacks from 15 ft. away like with the exotic weapons awl pike (*Dragon Compendium Volume 1* 110, 111) (10 gp; 10 lbs.) or meteor hammer (*Dragon* #319 73) (3 gp; 4 lbs.) that each have 15 ft. reach, the cleric can beat on that cornered undead with impunity without ending the turning effect. But if, for whatever reason and under normal circumstances, the cleric afterward approaches within 10 ft., the turn effect ends.

I assume that a typical Medium cleric in such a situation it's expected that the cleric turns undead from 15 ft. away or more, stays 15 ft. away or more, and employs his free sling and free sling stones and pelt the turned and cornered undead into oblivion.

Note that a typical Medium cleric's inability to unload melee attacks against turned and cornered undead creatures—because that typical cleric must be adjacent to the cornered undead to make melee attacks against it—is, in this DM and player's opinion, one of the main things that makes [turn undead a significantly worse option than rebuke undead](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/99327/8610).

Comment: There is no mention of a minimum range for Turn Undead to be used from in the PHB, and the text you quoted also states that a Cleric may stand within 10ft if they are not approaching. Does making a melee attack count as approaching, then?

Comment: (Ace stuff! I did not know such weapons existed!) However, you still seem to be approaching the question as if the cleric turns the creature, and then approaches. What if he is adjacent and then turns the creature? As he doesn't need to approach, he can make any other melee attack also? Or is the direct interaction considered approaching?

Comment: @royalmurder Sorry about that. How's that?

Comment: Ok, so *finally* got around to reading through this again; you'd actually hit the nail on the head. I'll go ahead and accept this now!

Answer (score 2):

Disclamer: this answer contains some degree of speculation.

When creature becomes turned, you may think of it as turned creature having 10' area expanding from it. While in this area (either initially or after subsequent movement), turning cleric can't approach further. She can attack turned creature without breaking effects of turning only from the border of this area. And once she is outside she can attack. Attacks must be with ranged weapons, and not with melee weapons (at least not with all of them, probably).

Relevant parts are:

- > You can stand within 10 feet without breaking the turning effect—you just can’t approach them.

  So, the fact of being within aforementioned area itself doesn't break effects of turning. Turning cleric can stand within 10 feet, she can stand within 5 feet, she may even share turned creature's space; untill she isn't approaching further, turning works.
- > You can attack them with ranged attacks (from at least 10 feet away)...

  So, turning cleric should remain at the edge of or out of aforementioned area to attack with a ranged weapons. She can't just shoot adjacent covering undead. Why even include the part in parenthesis otherwise?
  **Speculations begin.** You must note, there is a bunch of ways to attack from 10 feet away with a melee attack, but rules don't even mention melee attacks. This fact srongly suggests, that turning cleric can't make melee attacks against turned creature without breaking the turning. However, reach weapons are notorous for kind-of-counting-as-ranged-weapons for one rules area (various special abiliries which may be generalized as barbs and spikes on creature's hide; [Fire Shield spell](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/fireShield.htm)) which may be relevant here. So, it may be questionable if turning cleric wielding reach weapon should be disallowed to attack turned creature from at least 10 feet away without breaking effects of turning.
  **Further speculation.** There is a class of actions without clear definition incorporating actions which, not strictly being attacks, count as attacks for several effects ([invisibility](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/invisibility.htm) and [sanctuary](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/sanctuary.htm) breaking ones). For the sake of completeness, you as a DM may consider how do they interact with turning and if they even should.